# Passing parameters as string in ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Whenever this code is running when we pass variable in numbers, at the same time when i use string this code is not working.. any help greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           // $("input#pnum").hide();
            $("#cat").change(function(){
                var deptid = $(this).val();
//var value = $( this ).val();
//    $( ".deptid" ).text( value );
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajaxdropdown.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {depart:deptid},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(response){

                        var len = response.length;
                        var name1234 = "";
                        $("#pnum").empty();
                        for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                            var id1234 = response[i]['id123'];
                            name1234 += (name1234.length < 1) ? response[i]['name123'] : ',' + response[i]['name123'];
                          $("#pnum").val(name1234);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: What error do you get exactly? Please specify.

Comment: @OsamaIbrahim actually there is no error this coding is working for whenever change my drop down list then based on phone number fetch by the db values.. actually its working fine when i using drop down box value is 1,2,3,4,5 but when i using string then dept1,dept2,dept3 etc its not working

Comment: Are you sure your database is returning values for dept1, dept2 etc?

Comment: @OsamaIbrahim my database is returning values for when i using numbers.... instead of using string then it wont work :(

Comment: So your database must not be having any values against those strings if I'm not wrong.